# Generate variables with consecutive values

Tags: python, enums

I am working with a table with lots of columns. 
 In order not to get magic numbers, I code  something like this

```
colName, colID, colDesc = 1, 2, 3
```

When I want to add a new item, it becomes

```
#        vvvvvvvv                           v
colName, colAddr, colID, colDesc = 1, 2 ,3, 4
```

I add in `colAddr` where I want it and a 4 at the end.  This works with 4 variables but with about 20-30, I get very long lines of code.

So I separated them: one line each

```
colName = 1
colID = 2
colDesc = 3
```

If I wish to add something between Name and ID, I would have to renumber the variables which is really painful

```
colName = 1
colAddr = 2
colID = 3 # renumbered
colDesc = 4 # renumbered
```

I may have to add columns in between quite often - the table design is still fluid, so I thought of something like this

```
col = 0
col, colName = col + 1, col
col, colID = col + 1, col
col, colDesc = col + 1, col
```

If I wanted to add `colAddr`, then it would just be a one line change

```
col = 0
col, colName = col + 1, col
col, colAddr = col + 1, col # new line of code
col, colID = col + 1, col
col, colDesc = col + 1, col
```

This works but looks really messy.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can use [the `enum` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum).

Comment: `a,b,c=range(3)` just change the range amount

Comment: Use actual objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `a,b,c=range(3)` you can add any number of variables at the beginning and change the range value to match the number of variables.

If numbering needs to start at 1 use `range(1,4)`

Comment: So to stop the long lines, I just terminate each line with a \.  This would work for me.  I'll mark this one as the answer since it is the solution I would use the most often.

Answer (score 4):

A more elegant solution than the one @depperm suggests is to use [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) module (available starting from Python v. 3.4), e.g.:

```
from enum import Enum
class MyEnum (Enum):
    col, colName, colAddr, colID, colDesc = range(5)
```

Then you use it in the following way:

```
MyEnum.col
MyEnum.colName
...
```

You can of course use non-consequtive values for each of the variables.

Comment: I'm still getting used to the idea of enum classes in C++ and C#.  Didn't know they existed in Python too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collections.namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

t = namedtuple('columns', 'colName, colAddr, colID, colDesc')
cols = t._make(range(len(t._fields)))

print(cols)
print(cols.colName)
print(cols.colAddr)
print(cols.colID)
print(cols.colDesc)
```

Prints:

```
columns(colName=0, colAddr=1, colID=2, colDesc=3)
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do this in Python.  I've done something similar in TCL.